# Unable to create Pkcs11SignatureToken with JDK21

Tags: digital-signature, pkcs#11, electronic-signature, pades, dsss

## While using JDK 9 to 21 Getting this error Can't initialize Sun PKCS#11 security provider. Reason: Unable to instantiate PKCS11 (JDK >= 9) that is DSSException.

In request PKCS11 .dll and PIN and This DLL is working fine with jdk 1.8

This is my code:

[Calling Pkcs11SignatureToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3iiZ.png)

Exception:
[Getting this Ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWEmm.png)

> I am using now JDK 1.8 but i want to update with jdk 21 , Please help me out